# Introduction to Strict Cyclicity

Tags: phonology, reference-request, generative-grammar

Does anyone have any good references for an introduction to the theory of strict cyclicity within Generative Phonology?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you start here. This article disputes the SC theory, but contains good references to the origins of the theory.

Hualde, José Ignacio (1989) The Strict Cycle Condition and Noncyclic Rules, Linguistic Inquiry Vol. 20, No. 4, pp. 675-680

Answer (score 0):

You should trace back from Mascaró's dissertation, mentioned in Hualde's article on SSC. The immediate predecessors would be Kean (1974) "The Strict Cycle in Phonology" (LI 5: 179-203) and Kiparsky 1974 "Phonological representations" in *Three Dimensions in Linguistic Theory* ed. by Osamu Fujimura. Kiparsky's work on the Revised Alternation Condition is relevant to SSC, since these two have been seen as analogous to electricity and magnetism ("the same thing"). SSC originates (non-phonologically) from Chomsky 1971 "Conditions on transformations". The Kean article is about Klamath and is a kind of response to papers by Kisseberth especially his articles "The Strict Cyclicity Principle: The Klamath Evidence" (Kisseberth ed. *Studies in Generative Phonology*, 1973) and (1972) "Cyclic Rules in Klamath Phonology", *Linguistic Inquiry* 3: 1-34. Kean also cites Halle 1973 "The Accentuation of Russian Words" (*Language* 49: 312-348) who cites Kean 1971 which is a never-published paper entitled "Strict Cyclicity". I seem not to have Kisseberth's Strict Cycle paper, but I assume it mentions Kean's MS and Halle's *Language* paper.